# PHP login screen

Tags: php, html, oracle-call-interface

I'm making a login screen using PHP. I have a HTML file and a PHP file. My HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Loginscreen.css" />
    <title>Inloggen</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="login">
  <div id="triangle"></div>
  <h1>Inloggen</h1>
  <form method="get" action="Control.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" name="log" required />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" name ="pas" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Inloggen" />
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('test', 'test', 'test');
$username1 = $_GET['log'];
$password1 = $_GET['pas'];
$array = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT test_A, test_b FROM test WHERE test_A = '$username1'  AND test_b =  '$password1'");
$query = oci_execute($array);

$count = oci_fetch_row($array);

if($count > 1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['Login'] = "1";
    header("Location: page1.html");
}
else {
    ?>
<script>
    alert("Wrong username/password");
    location.href = "Login.php";
</script>
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['Login'] = "";
}
?>
```

When I submit, the page is giving an error:

```
define() expects at least 2 parameters 1 given at line 3 from the php file
```

How do I fix this error?
I tried to set a define around the connection string, but then I gain the same error.

Comment: It says you are using define keyword wrong. But in your code you don't have define at all, so error must be somewhere else, in some other file.

Comment: Are you including any file? Kindly share code from that file.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's causing the error as you're not using any `define()` function calls, but you might want to use `PDO` or `oci_bind_by_name()` as your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 3):

Function of `define` should be:

```
define('YOUR_CONST','YOUR_VALUE');
```

Reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php